# Closed Pipe error while doing sftp in vm using docker

Tags: docker, apache-camel, sftp

I have a dockerized container of camel router which does sftp from remote host to VM local folder.  If I just run my code in VM in conventional way (ie java -jar my-sftp-camel-router.jar), it downloads all 5000 files. However, when I run the same as docker image using docker run -P /tmp/:/tmp/ my-sftp-camel-router-image  it fails after downloading around 12 files.
Both cases works fine in my local machine, but not on VM.

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot change directory to: /
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.doChangeDirectory(SftpOperations.java:576)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(SftpOperations.java:533)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.buildDirectory(SftpOperations.java:472)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.renameFile(GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.java:106)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.begin(GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.java:43)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:367)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:137)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:226)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 4: 
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:359)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.doChangeDirectory(SftpOperations.java:574)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:307)
at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2882)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2908)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._realpath(ChannelSftp.java:2328)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:342)
... 18 more
```